# Laravel 5. Не удаляются записи из БД

Tags: php, laravel

Котроллер MessagesController:

```
    public function destroy(Messages $message)
{
    $message->delete();
    return redirect()->route('messages.index')->with('message', 'Запись удалена.');
}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController@index');
Route::post('messages.store', ['as' => 'messages.store', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@store']);
Route::delete('messages.destroy', ['as' => 'messages.destroy', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@destroy']);
```

Страница вида:

```
    {!! Form::open(array('route'=>['messages.destroy',$message->id],'method'=>'DELETE')) !!}
        {!! Form::button('Удалить',['class'=>'btn btn-danger','type'=>'submit']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

При нажатии на кнопку выводится сообщение об удалении однако этого не происходит. По прежнему выводится на странице вида.

Comment: Попробуй сперва удалить без  депенденси инъекции, $id, $message = Message::find($id)->delete();

Comment: Не стоило называть active record во множественном числе. А ежели `Messages` у вас класс коллекции, в `delete` нужно передавать хотя бы `$id`

Answer (score 0):

Для начала посмотрите с помощью print_r ил var_dump запрос $request есть ли там переменная id сообщения.

```
use App\Messagges; //загрузка модели сообщения
public function destroy(Request $post)
{
    $messagge=new Messagges;
    $messagge::find($post['id_messagge']); //сначала находим
    $messagge->delete(); //затем удаляем.
    return redirect()->route('messages.index')->with('message', 'Запись удалена.');
}
```